# Как менять спрайт у кнопки при нажатии на нее

Tags: unity3d

Совсем недавно начал создавать игру на юнити и столкнулся с проблемой. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку у нее менялся спрайт. В теории понимаю, но не хватает знаний. Уже кучу информации перечитал и все равно не получается

Comment: `В теории понимаю, но не хватает знаний.` - так нельзя. Лучше предоставить хотя бы те наработки, которые у вас уже есть, чтобы показать, что вы пытались что-то сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какой-то простой вопрос. Неужели не нашли в Интернете?

```
public Sprite newSprite;

public void OnClick () {
    GetComponent<Image>().sprite = newSprite;
}
```

- newSprite - спрайт после нажатия.
- Скрипт с этим кодом вешаем на кнопку.
- В компоненте Button нажимаем +, указываем объект самому себе, выбираем правее метод OnClick().

---

Если у вас кнопка реализована не через компонент Button, а через BoxCollider2D, то скрипт будет:

```
private void OnMouseDown () {
    GetComponent<Image>().sprite = newSprite;
}
```

Просто вешаем скрипт на кнопку и все.

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, примите его, поставив галочку.